# PowerDesigner - vbs script to run other scripts

Tags: powerdesigner

I have a few PowerDesigner 15 vbs scripts that perform various cleansing/transformation tasks   on physical data models.

I'd like to be able to run all of them at once rather than one at a time (there are 10 scripts now, possibly more in the future).

Also, I'd like to avoid copying all the code in one big ugly script.

Is there a way to have a script that runs all other scripts?

*Note: I've tried **ExecuteCommand**, but it doesn't work; it executes the .vbs outside the context of PowerDesigner, so it cannot access the Model.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your scripts in an extension (.xem).

The main script would attach the extension to the model, use the scripts (as custom methods on the model object for example), and detach the extension at the end?

Or you could even always attach the extension to your model (which would allow defining the cleansing scripts as popup menu options).

Comment: The great thing in using Model Extensions is that now I can also add my custom methods as context-menu items on various object types (e.g. Model, Table, Column). I wasn't aware of that until now. Thank you very much!